# Thoughts on this conversion of code from Step.js to Q promise library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I have some code that I'd written using this pattern with [Step.js](https://github.com/creationix/step).  In this case, talking to MongoDB in Node:

```
Step(
    function connectToDatabaseWithAuthorization() {
        mongodb.connect(mongoConnectURI, this);
    },

    function getCommitCollection(err, conn) {
        if (err) handleResErr(res, err);

        conn.collection('commits', this);
    },

    function addCommitToCollection(err, coll) {
        if (err) handleResErr(res, err);

        var commit = JSON.parse(req.param('commit', null));
        commit.commit_date = requestTime;
        commit.commit_id = common.makeIdFromCommit(commit);
        coll.insert(commit, {safe: true}, this);
    },

    function respondWithShowAndVerifyUrlsInJson(err, records) {
        if (err) handleResErr(res, err);

        res.json({
            commit_date: records[0].commit_date
        });
    }
)
```

When I went to update my Node libraries, I noticed Step wasn't getting much attention or undergoing much development.  And I wasn't happy about the error handling being spread into each function in the steps.

So I went to research modern alternatives, and [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) seemed more popular.  But when I asked about how to convert it, someone [suggested I look into Q Promises instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22154290/211160).

I came up with this transformation, which seems to work:

```
Q.try(function() {

    return Q.ninvoke(mongodb, 'connect', mongoConnectURI);

}).then(function (conn) {

    return Q.ninvoke(conn, 'collection', 'commits');

}).then(function (coll) {

    var commit = JSON.parse(req.param('commit', null));
    commit.commit_date = requestTime;
    commit.commit_id = common.makeIdFromCommit(commit);
    return Q.ninvoke(coll, 'insert', commit, {safe: true});

}).then(function (records) {

    res.json({
        commit_date: records[0].commit_date
    });

}).catch(function (err) {

    handleResErr(res, err);

});
```

Not a large piece of code, but I could use a sanity check.  I was having problems with figuring out if I should be using `.done()` in there somewhere, and also I couldn't get `.finally` to work.  If I put it on the end of the chain, it ran after the first promise and not after all of them.  :-/

While I mostly think the generality makes it an improvement, it does really obscure the method calls.  `Q.ninvoke(mongodb, 'connect' mongoConnectURI)` is quite a bit uglier than `mongodb.connect(mongoConnectURI)`.  Have people made some better way to do mongodb calls with promises than this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting that you're getting `.finally()` after your first method rather than at the end. Should I read that to mean that your code executed as: connect-->finally-->[DONE] or did control flow somewhere else in the promise chain subsequent to `finally`?

Regarding the aesthetics - I couldn't agree with your more; `ninvoke` and its relatives are not the easiest to read. Two main options. One, you can look for a promise-enabled library for this or that. This is probably not my first choice unless the library would be giving you something more than just a promises wrapper. Two, you can get yourself some nicer looking functions by using the `denodeify` function. Consider if you wrote a module like this (you could of course inline this code as well which I often do for both initial development as well as if I find I really don't need more than a function or two):

```
var Q = require('q');
var lib = require('someNodeModule');

module.exports = {
   connect: Q.denodeify(lib.connect),
   read: Q.denodeify(lib.read),
   write: Q.denodeify(lib.write)
}
```

At this point, you have a new module with each of the above functions being promise-returning ones rather than callback-invoking ones. If you `require` the above as, say `libp`, you could then replace your various `return Q.ninvoke(...)` calls with much more clear calls such as a simple `return libp.connect(...)`. The signature of the function stays the same (other than the obvious loss of the final callback).

I will try to return to this later this evening as well regarding the odd `.finally()` behavior. In the meantime, you might find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112801/node-js-using-promises-with-mongodb/19149119#19149119) relevant to an issue you did not raise, but may encounter. More generally, the individual providing the answer, Bergi, appears to be quite expert with promises (from other answers I have seen), so you might check out some other answers or even solicit input on this. I am a journeyman, at best, with promises. I think I have a reasonable understanding of the concepts and library, but have not yet accumulated all the idioms that would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, it seems the .finally() issue is something with the console.log messages being out of chronological order in Nodejitsu's **jitsu logs tail** feature.  That is certainly confusing for someone already out of their usual toolset already.  :-/  Still confused about the .done()... some people use it, some don't.  What's the point?  Is it okay that my last `.then` clause returns nothing, and if so what makes that okay?

Comment: Good old `console.log()` - it's great having such an easy logger always available, but it occasionally has me chasing non-errors because of the timing of messages (and the fact that it seems if I crash out on some code, the not-yet-emitted messages are lost). As for `.done()`, I tend not to use it and often see it omitted, but it appears I should, having read [the API doc](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress)

Comment: Things have been going along pretty well; I'd say the promise library was a good choice.  Thanks for the help and the original suggestion!  Feel free to test [blackhighlighter](http://blackhighlighter.org/write/), if it happens to be up and working.  :-)